# Javascript/Node.JS find text between two strings, multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, delimiter

I need to find the text between begin and end, multiple times. I have a regex expression setup, but it only finds the first instance. Is there a way that I could make it find every "text" and then I can call them separately as an array, i.e., instances[1], instances[2], etc. I am using Node.JS so I cannot use the DOM as some other answers have applied.

```
begin
text 
end

begin

text 

end

begin
text 

end

begin

text 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes append /g to the end of the regular expression to match all occurrences like so:

```
let myArr = "begin middle end".match(/regularExpression/g)
```

Below is a snippet for your purposes:

```js
var input = "begin middle end";
var regex = /begin\s(.*)\send/g;

var matches;
while (matches = regex.exec(input)) {
  console.log(matches);
  console.log('Middle text is: ' + matches[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression will be something like this:

`/begin\n([\w ]+)\nend/g`

Note the `g` at the end for global match.

Comment: This works, but only if there is no whitespace separating the middle text. If there are two new lines between begin and the text it won't match it.